How to create swipe up stories using Facebook Graph API?
Based on this document, I can create stories on my page, but I don't see any mention of how to set up CTA buttons like Learn more, See more,... to lead users to the website.
Can we do this through the Graph API?
Please let me know the keyword or link to the document if you know it.
Thanks so much!
